# Send GET request with 443 userid password prompt authentication using Java HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I want to get the response from a url by sending url parameters(GET parameters)
eg.
https://ebctest.cybersource.com/ebctest/DownloadReport/2014/07/23/$MerchantId/ConversionDetailReport.xml

When I hit the server I am prompted by a userid, password dialog box.

I can get the response by manually entering the id,password.
How can I achieve this programatically using java.

Below is the code which I have tried till now.

```
final HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, 443), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", Integer.valueOf(10000));
httpClient.getState().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);            

final GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://ebctest.cybersource.com/ebctest/DownloadReport/2014/07/23/$merchantId/ConversionDetailReport.xml");

final InputSource is = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(method.getResponseBody()));
```

When I do method.getResponseBody I get empty. I should be getting a proper response as I am getting when sending the request manually.

Comment: There are some important informations missing: What happens with the code you tried? What did you expect instead?

Comment: added some more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it Looks like basic auth, you should be able to send username and password by calling this url:

https://**username**:**password**@ebctest.cybersource.com/ebctest/D

Comment: or use the authentication header like: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-to-a-url-using-basic-authentication.html